# react-native build failing due to PhaseScriptExecution error

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

**Environment**

```
Mac OS X Version 12.1 (Apple M1 chip)
Xcode Version 13.2.1
Simulator Version 13.2 (972.2)
react-native-cli 7.0.3
node v18.4.0
```

**The Issue**

This is my first time working on developing an app using React Native. I am trying to run my React Native project on Xcode's simulator, using `npx react-native run-ios`. However, I am encountering this error message.

```
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening MCompass.xcworkspace.
Command line invocation:
    /Users/brx/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace MCompass.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme MCompass -destination id=DC3C75E6-19FD-4B80-87B1-62BF6404ED20

...

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution Bundle\ React\ Native\ code\ and\ images /Users/brx/src/projects/test/MCompass/ios/build/MCompass.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MCompass.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh (in target 'MCompass' from project 'MCompass')
(1 failure)
```

Between the first error message and `** BUILD FAILED **`, there were many lines of output listing exports.

I've installed dependencies using both `yarn` and `npm`. I've also looked at several other threads with this same issue, but none of the solutions (such as having only one version of `nvm` or running `react-native upgrade`) have been successful. Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: Hi, Please try to run Xcode with Rosetta.  This link will help you -- https://community.appdynamics.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/How-do-I-run-the-iOS-simulator-on-my-M1-based-Mac/ta-p/46825

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice! I ran Xcode with Rosetta, but the build failed again, this time only with the "Failed to build iOS project" error mentioned above. I also received a warning that Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in two paths, and I don't know what that means.

Comment: Running sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app should fixed the issue.

Comment: I just tried that, and the original PhaseScriptExecution error came back, even though I did not change anything else.

Comment: try restarting mac. also check xcode is running with Rosetta only

Answer (score 1):

- I had my root folder name "REACT NATIVE", changing it to "REACT_NATIVE" fixed the error as the folder that contains your react native project cannot contain white spaces.
- The second solution would be running Xcode with rosetta. This is only applicable for M1 chip macbooks as there are few times Xcode projects fail because of this reason. Please refer to below link for reference:

https://penny-huang.medium.com/xcode-how-to-run-ios-simulator-on-m1-mac-66101b9fccd8